# aws memory high usage

Tags: memory, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, glassfish

Recently I configured my instance into a micro environment in EC2 with glassfish and mysql in windows..
I deployed my war and i was able to access my site through http.

I changed my application and redeployed the war and it also worked.

When I was about to redeploy the war for 4th or 5th time, the application got deployed, I saw the message in the log file. But I was unable to access the site through http.

Then I tried the command "asadmin list-applications" and I got the following message.

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM 
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
```

After that I was not able to connect to my instance through RDP and I had to reboot, I was able to access it again after that. I started the servers again (glassfish mysql), but no luck.

```
I noticed that the memory usage is around 90% or more. CPU isage is low.
```

now I can not access my site through http. what shall i do ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Honestly, there are a couple issues working against you here:

1) Windows requires FAR more RAM than Ubuntu to run at a minimum decent level.
2) GlassFish has a much larger footprint than Tomcat or Jetty.

Is there any particular reason you need Windows?  Like is there a specific need that your server run some executables for file processing or something like that outside the JVM?  Most would agree that Linux (Ubuntu or other) will give you much better results in performance and stability to run an App Server like GlassFish in any environment.

Comment: There are no particular reason for choosing Windows. I chose windows because I'm new to hosting in amazon and did not know how to install and configure glassfish, mysql in ubuntu... so chose Windows and it was working fine.. Are you suggesting that I should go for Ubuntu Linux in a micro instance ?

Comment: Hi I hosted it in amazon linux and this seems to be better so far.. still using glassfish as I am using some ejb component that tomcat will not support.

Comment: Yeah I have used Ubuntu 10.x 64-bit in EC2 Micro instances for little projects I do.  It's been very successful.  Linux can do a lot with 640MB RAM.

Comment: agree. it works much better in amazon-linux now and it's free too for a micro instance...